# How to use data.frame columns as vectors

Tags: r

I'm trying to separate the columns (`Grith`, `Height` and `Volume`) from the data.frame of a given data set package. How to I extract the columns as "plain" R vectors?

```
library("tree")
data(trees)
str(trees)
'data.frame':   31 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Girth : num  8.3 8.6 8.8 10.5 10.7 10.8 11 11 11.1 11.2 ...
 $ Height: num  70 65 63 72 81 83 66 75 80 75 ...
 $ Volume: num  10.3 10.3 10.2 16.4 18.8 19.7 15.6 18.2 22.6 19.9 ...
> summary(trees)
     Girth           Height       Volume     
 Min.   : 8.30   Min.   :63   Min.   :10.20  
 1st Qu.:11.05   1st Qu.:72   1st Qu.:19.40  
 Median :12.90   Median :76   Median :24.20  
 Mean   :13.25   Mean   :76   Mean   :30.17  
 3rd Qu.:15.25   3rd Qu.:80   3rd Qu.:37.30  
 Max.   :20.60   Max.   :87   Max.   :77.00
```

Comment: @RichardScriven essentially, i'm looking to subset via the data names (Grith, Height and Volume)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is make use of the vectors from that data frame, then either use attach(trees) or call them by name: trees$Girth

Is that all you're asking? If not, please elaborate.

Comment: Yes. That's what i'm looking for. I didn't realize you can do this way. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Treating the data frame as a list: `trees[["Girth"]]`

Using the `row, column` indexing of `[`: `trees[, "Girth"]`

Using the `$`-to-extract shortcut `trees$Girth`

Answer (score -1):

factor is probably not a good choice as the variables are all numeric and you don't really need melt if you are not reshaping the data. a simple which() should do if you are selecting a subset of these variables or a combination of them.